# Bootstrap navbar collapse - how to close by clicking away

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I guess this is a noob question. I want Bootstrap "navbar-collapse" to close by clicking away or by clicking one of list items. I found this code somewhere and it works.

```
$(document).on('click',function() {
    $('.collapse').collapse('hide');
});
```

But this code also makes Bootstrap "panel-collapse" elements close by clicking away and of course I don't want this to happen.

How can I specify that I want this code to work only for "navbar-collapse" elements?

Answer (score 1):

Give your navbar collapse elements a new class and assign it inside:

```
$('.NewClassName').collapse('hide');
```

Note that you ADD that class to the navbar collapse elements without removing the old class.

Comment: Thanks. Your bit of code works even with standard Bootstrap class "navbar-collapse". I used it with errors earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct.

The above displayed a weird behavior for me where sometimes a scroll bar would appear on the nav. That could be from some fancy css but the below fixed it for me.

```
$(document).on('click',function(e){
  if($('#navbar-collapse').hasClass('in')){
    $('.collapse').collapse('hide'); 
  }
})
```

Also, make sure you have the

```
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

in your file.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you are clicking outside the navbar. Collapse method can be fired expectedly by using our reference to the navbar

```
$(document).click(function (event) {
    var target = $(event.target);
    var $navbar = $(".navbar-collapse");               
    var opened = $navbar.hasClass("in");
    if (opened === true && !target.hasClass("navbar-toggle")) {      
        $navbar.collapse('hide');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the bootstrap `navbar` class, you can simply do:

```
$('.navbar .collapse').collapse('hide');
```

This will hide all collapse elements which are children of the `navbar` class.